# Not showing Deploy Preview button in Android Studio for com.android.library modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm probably missing something obvious but I'm unable to show the [Deploy Preview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview-features) button in my Android Studio.

[image]

However if I open the [Android Compose Samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) I see them.

I checked their dependencies and applied them to my app, but I'm still not able to see them.

```kotlin
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.1.0-rc02'
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.1.0-rc01"
```

What am I missing to make this deploy preview show?

### Edit

To be clear I'm able show previews no problem.
But no deploy preview button.

[image]

### Edit 2

I noticed that the button is only appearing in `'com.android.application'` modules and not in `'com.android.library'` modules  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do you have some errors displayed? On the top right corner of the preview panel. The preview won't work with ViewModel for instance

Comment: Also did you add `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'`? I think I didn't get previews at some point while trying to remove useless dependencies

Comment: The preview is displaying no problems. However I'm not even able to show a deploy preview for a simple `Box` `Composable`

Comment: I updated the question to include my actual dependencies and a screenshot of my Android Studio not even able to show a deploy preview for a simple Box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is only visible in an Android library.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    ...
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        ... 
...
```

This is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160491871) in Android Studio.

Unfortunately it is not documented anywhere except for [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160491871).
It has been fixed in **Chipmunk Canary 2**

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable it on the experimental panel in AS settings?

Also, I believe you're missing the preview dependency
`implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"`

[image]

Comment: Did all of the above, but to no avail unfortunately

Comment: I have noticed that it is only happening in android library modules, not in application modules

Comment: That's odd, I made a library a few weeks ago and I could use the preview just fine in the library module as well. But I didn't check if the deploy was visible so could be the reason as you mentioned in your answer